# Suppose K:Q is normal with Gal(K:Q) isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_6$. Prove that K has 3 distinct non-trivial square roots.

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

Suppose K:Q is normal with Gal(K:Q) isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_6$.  Prove that K has 3 distinct non-trivial square roots.

Q is the set of rational numbers.
The only clue that I've been given is that $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_6$ has 3 subgroups of size 12.

Comment: You should look at what the data you start with implies under the Galois correspondence.

Comment: What do you mean by the square root of a field?

Comment: @Greg, I'm sure James means $K$ contains $\sqrt n$ for three distinct nonsquare integers. (Though of course what James really wants is more than just that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisely one should say: Prove that $K/\mathbb Q$ has three distinct intermediate fields of degree $2$ over $\mathbb Q$ (Because such an intermediate field corresponds to a square root of a square-free integer).

By Galois correspondence this is equivalent to the fact that the galois group has three distinct subgroups of index $2$ (and thus order $12$). So your hint immediately solves the exercise.